# How can I execute an INSERT query on Twig (symfony 3)?

Tags: php, checkbox, twig, symfony

the problem than I want to resolve is than I want to see a list of users, and then I want to have a checkbox next to each user to select if the user is present or if it is ausent. On symfony (basic HTML actually) I can create an array than give me the id of those than I selected previously on the form, but, how can I send that information to the database? since I have this data on the view (which is a twig file on symfony).

So far I have only found this example of how to create a query from twig https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/591299/hackishly-using-SQL-in-Twig-templates-in , but it give me an error since it doesnt recognize the "db", so I cant use it.

So, is there any way to to send that array to the database? Twig seems to limit a lot my options. Thanks

Edit: Correct approach (because someone else will have this noob doubt in the future, as I did) is in the method of the form (easier to make it work by just using html instead of what twig offer) call the method from the controller than you want to call, and there you can get the data with a $_GET or $_POST and then interact with the database with doctrine.

Comment: emphasis on the word *hackishly* in the script you linked. It's bad enough to try and perform a SELECT, but an INSERT is actively modifying data which really breaks the architecture Symfony tries to promote. I'd suggest learning more about what Twig is intended to do (it shouldn't be doing SQL). I suspect what you're trying to achieve can't even be done with Twig as Twig only runs once for each page load - you will need JS or read the data in a controller if you're doing this via submitting a form.

Comment: @HPierce thanks for the response, and your point is right, but since I have an array generated on the view (twig in this case), I cant see how to send that array to the database other that trying to send it from twig. Of course I can create a checkbox on the userType file (than build the form), but it only let me have one checkbox per page, even if I put it inside a 'for'

Answer (score 3):

Twig is not limiting you. You are limiting yourself by using Twig in the worst possible way :) The main purpose of Twig is rendering your templates, not processing your raw queries. You're just ruining your performance, because the code which you write in Twig is read by a Twig interpreter first - that's unnecessary overhead.

You should put your database logic in services (use Doctrine for that - no need to write raw SQL for such simple queries). Use those services in controllers. And finally, pass the data from controller to template and render it using Twig.

If you want to have some dynamic actions after the page is loaded - write some simple JavaScript and make use of AJAX (background) requests to your controllers to send or get some additional data from your server. Or use Web Sockets if you prefer your data to be pushed to your page in real time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, your approach on the first paragraph is the way to go